# Best scraper/crawler needed for multipage forms (Nokogiri, Scrapy, other?)

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, mechanize, mechanize-python, mechanize-ruby

I've read that Nokogiri/Mechanize (Ruby) for example are not good at traversing multiple pages, but may be better with sites that use Ajax.

The sites I want to scrape are multi-page forms, with some ajax overlays.  Speed is important.  These sites all display prices, so I am making a price aggregator.

Comment: Scraping and Crawling are different things. Scrapy excels at both.

Answer (score 0):

I use Capybara with Webkit to a headless browser.

You'll need install capybara gem, and webkit gem as well.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit

The syntax is very simple.

```
agent.visit 'some url'
agent.execute_script 'javascript here'
```

The gem also have page management, or you may simply go back to previous page by execute a javascript going back.

```
ag.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```